# Delay a function, any function!

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to solve an issue with an implementation of Woocommerce I am working on. At the end of the thankyou page I call a function to auto complete the order if it is a virtual one.
This in turns trigger other functions that takes a noticeable amount of time to be executed (creates a big array of codes in the DB and connects these to the order). That was expected, I planned to have this process going on as background.

What was not expected is that this stalls the thankyou page creation.

Basically it waits until everything is completed, prior to complete the thankyou page.
Note that there is not anything the thankyou page need to display from the other processes. It simply get frozen in place while that thread hogs all the power.

It seems to me that everything gets executed in a single PHP thread; if it is doing something, it cannot do anything else.

Is there any way for me to delay the launch of that function until the thankyou page has been displayed to the customer?

I was looking at cron jobs to autocomplete the orders, but maybe that would be unreliable. Don't exactly have idea of how to implement it.

I have found other mentions of this problem in other threads, but nothing that looked like a "golden standard" way to implement this sort of delays.

Thank you all for your help in solving that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this via WP Cron using [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/). However, for this to properly work, you'd need to disable the standard cron (which is run by a user visiting the site) and instead use a proper cronjob/crontab. EasyEngine has a good tutorial on [disabling wp-cron and using cronjob instead](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/wordpress/wp-cron-crontab/).

An alternative would be solve this via an AJAX request. You could invoke the function via JS on the thank you page. The [docu explains how to do this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)), in simple terms it could look like this

```
<script>
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'do_my_long_action',
        'data':   'some_data'
    }, 
    function(response){
        //
    }
);
</script>
```

and

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_do_my_long_action', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // handle request

    // sent success message (or wp_die())
    wp_send_json(

    );
}
```